# php composer run install library do not work

Tags: php, composer-php

I try to create a PHP class to install a new composer library.

It removes all the other library inside `composer.json`

Do you have any idea to add a library without to remove all the libraries?

thank you

```
public static function install(string $packages)
{
  if ($packages == self::dump()) {
    return false;
  }

  putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . BASE_DIRECTORY . 'External/vendor/bin/composer');

  self::createComposerJson($packages);

  // Setup composer output formatter
  $stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
  $output = new StreamOutput($stream);

  // Programmatically run `composer install`
  $application = new Application();
  $application->setAutoExit(false);
  $application->run(new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'install')), $output);

  // remove composer.lock
  if (file_exists(static::$root . 'composer.lock')) {
    unlink(static::$root . 'composer.lock');
  }
  // rewind stream to read full contents
  rewind($stream);
  return stream_get_contents($stream);
}

/**
 * @param $packages
 * @return false|int
 */
protected static function createComposerJson($packages) {
  $array = [
    array(
      'config' => array('vendor-dir' => self::VENDOR_DIR),
      'require' => $packages,
      //
      // TODO:
      // windowsazure requires PEAR repository
      //
      'repositories' => array(array(
        'type' => 'pear',
        'url' => 'http://pear.php.net'
      )),
      'preferred-install' => 'dist'
    )
  ];

  $composer_json = str_replace("\/", '/', json_encode($array));

  return file_put_contents(static::$root . 'composer.json', $composer_json, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

the result is that for composon.json. There is a problem

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "includes/ClicShopping/External/vendor"
    },
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "setasign/fpdf": "1.8.1",
        "phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc": "^4.0",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^6.0",
        "composer/composer": "^1.9"
    }
}
[{"config":{"vendor-dir":"vendor"},"require":"stripe/stripe-php","repositories":[{"type":"pear","url":"http://pear.php.net"}],"preferred-install":"dist"}]
```

Comment: See the entry direction for appending data using [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or use the [fwrite function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) with append flag (a+)

Comment: @Jamie_D, TK, I added this element but like you see above, there is a problem on json construction. Not work; Do you know php script works correctly woth composer ?